# Detailed, per URL statistics in WCAT

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, wcat, webapplicationstresstool

I used to use MS's Homer tool for quick load testing. That tool was great - it had an easy-to-use UI and provided detailed reports on a per URL basis.

I'm now switching over to WCAT because Homer is withdrawn and doesn't run on post-Vista versions of windows.

The reporting in WCAT seems much weaker than in Homer. Is there a way to get more detailed statistics than are presented in the default report?

Without per-URL statistics, how is one supposed to properly evaluate the performance of your site?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter can provide the detailed level you're looking for.  Take a look at the available listeners:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of JMeter. I'm hoping someone can give me an answer for WCAT though